# ANCOVA - F notation - very simple question

Tags: ancova

I can't understand the number with the F value ($F_{2, 89} = 0.93, p = 0.09$) in result section from the following paper.  Relevant section is quoted below.  Can anyone please explain this to me?

http://www.nature.com/srep/2013/130725/srep02259/full/srep02259.html?WT.ec_id=SREP-631-20130801

"At week 0 there was no difference in morphological measurements (ANCOVA with standard length as covariate; body depth $F_{2, 89} = 0.93, p = 0.09$; size of ocellus $F_{2, 89} = 0.47, p = 0.63$; eye diameter $F_{2, 89} = 0.65, p = 0.52$;) among fish from the three different treatments. After 6-weeks, prey that had been exposed to predator cues had significantly deeper bodies for any given length than fish from the two control treatments ($F_{2, 89} = 33.14, p<0.001$; Fig. 1a–c)."

Comment: "the number with the F value" is ambiguous. Are you asking for the meaning of "p-value" or of the subscripts on the F, or of the F-value itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parenthesis simply present the $F$ statistic along with the $P$ value.  The interpretation of an $F$ statistic is dependant upon the degrees of freedom present, and these are presented in the subscript ($F_{2,89}$).  The two variables are "morphological measurements" and "standard length", the first of which has 2 degrees of freedom ($n-1$) and the second has 89 degree of freedom.

More information [here](http://www.yorku.ca/mack/RN-HowToReportAnFStatistic.html)